# Apache FOP: fox:external-document and fo:external-graphic

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, apache-fop

i've got a problem with Apache FOP and creating PDF files. I'm trying to include an image as a header and an another pdf as an attachment.

Running my application (compiled with Java 8) on Windows it creates PDF with image header and PDF attachment; running the same jar on AS400 machine I got PDF only with image header and no attachment.
My jar is created with shade plugin; does exists a particular order in pom dependencies to obtain the same result on Windows and AS400?
Thanks in advance.